# Flexbox, fill width when wrapped without using media queries

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have flex parent with flex elements. I want to have this behavior:

- The space when in row mode is equally divided between flex children.
- Each child has a min-width of, let's say, 100px.
- When the width is less than 100px wrap the flexbox.
- When wrapped the children use max width.
- It would be great if I don't need media queries, it's relatively easy to do it with 'em.

Is this possible?

My code is:

```css
.connections>ul {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;

    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 20px;
}

.connections>ul>li {
    height: 50px;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.connection-button {
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: 0.3s;
    position: relative;
}

.discord-button {
    background-color: #5865F2;
}

.spotify-button {
    background-color: #1DB954;
}

.xbox-button {
    background-color: #107C10;
}

.steam-button {
    background-color: #1b2838;
}

.github-button {
    background-color: #14232c;
}

.gmail-button {
    background-color: #EA4335;
}

.discord-connection-button:hover {
    background-color: rgba(88, 101, 242, 0.6);
}

.spotify-connection-button:hover {
    background-color: rgba(30, 215, 96, 0.6);
}

.steam-connection-button:hover {
    background-color: rgba(68, 96, 130, 0.6);
}

.github-connection-button:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

.email-connection-button:hover {
    background-color: rgba(212, 70, 56, 0.6);
}
```

```html
  <div class="connections">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#discord" class="connection-button discord-button">Discord</a></li>
      <li><a href="#spotify" target="_blank" class="connection-button spotify-button">Spotify</a></li>
      <li><a href="#xbox" target="_blank" class="connection-button xbox-button">Xbox</a></li>
      <li><a href="#steam" target="_blank" class="connection-button steam-button">Steam</a></li>
      <li><a href="#github" target="_blank" class="connection-button github-button">Github</a></li>
      <li><a href="#email" class="connection-button gmail-button">Email</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Usually there are absolute position images with vectors inside of the `a` tags.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way this is possible with just CSS, without media queries. Alternatively you could use JS to add or remove classes, but it doesn't sound like that's what you want. Besides, media queries would be lighter than JS anyways, so that's probably the way to go.

Also, not sure what the project is for, but if you will have other developers working on it, they'll likely be looking for media queries, so sticking to the convention can be beneficial anyways.